# How to query App Store for complete app version history?

Tags: ios, app-store

I would like to add a feature to my iOS app which shows the app's version history with information about updated and new features.

Since this information is also available on the app's App Store page, I tried to simply query and parse this page (e.g. `https://apps.apple.com/us/app/facebook/id284882215` for the facebook app).

While this works fine in general it seems that the history information included on this page is **limited to the most recent updates** (25 entries). For example the history of the Facebook app only reaches back to September 2021.

**Is there any way to query the App Store for the complete version history?**

Answer (score 0):

The information you seek appears on their support page found referenced as of 12-2023 here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/read_app_store_version_information

TLDR: there is a limit of 50 results:

```
Query Parameters
limit[appStoreVersionLocalizations]
integer

Number of resources to return.
Maximum Value: 50
```

Comment: The question is specifically asking how to query the *complete* app history, not just the last 25 or 50 results.

Comment: It appears there is a hard limitation of 200 results, as found here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/list_all_app_store_versions_for_an_app